# Create generic object

Tags: apex, tasks, lookup-field

I am not able to create a Lookup to Task, EmailMessage and couple of other objects . So looks like there is a known limitation and hence Task and EmailMessage objects are not available in RelatedTo dropdown while creating lookup relationship field.

So I am trying to create objects for Task, EmailMessage etc dynamically and read records for these objects .

Can I place these object API names in meta data (Task, EmailMessage etc ) and read the string and split it based on delimeter and create objects ?

String ObjList = 'Task,EmailMessage' ( read from meta data)

sObject obj = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(lateBoundType).newSObject();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the name of an sObject, it's as simple as:

```
sObject record = ((sObject)Type.forName('Schema',objectName).newInstance()).getSObjectType();
```

If you have multiple sObjects in a list, you can split that string and do that, too:

```
sObject[] records = new sObject[0];
for(String objectName: objList.split(',')) {
  records.add(((sObject)Type.forName('Schema',objectName).newInstance()).getSObjectType());
}
```

Although, more intuitively, I'd prefer to start with a list if I'm calling something `objList`:

```
String[] objList = new String[] { 'Tasking', 'EmailMessage' };
```

To get or set field values in an sObject, use the `get(field)` and `put(field, value)` methods, respectively.

You can read more on how to use these and other features in the [Dynamic Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic.htm) documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response. You are really great